# How to fill UITableView with ASIHttpRequest JSON data?

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, uitableview, asihttprequest

i'm trying to fill my UITableView with [this JSON data](http://api.glennzo.nl/glow/index.json) using the ASIhttprequest, but ik get the following exception: `__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

I use the following code in my controller to achieve this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface tableListViewController : UITableViewController {
    NSDictionary *data;
}

@end
```

And the main file:

```
#import "tableListViewController.h"
#import "ASIHTTPRequest.h"
#import "ASIFormDataRequest.h"

@interface tableListViewController ()

@end

@implementation tableListViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.glennzo.nl/glow/index.json"];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setTag:100];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startSynchronous];

    //Set the title
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Events";
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void) requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *) request
{
    if (request.tag == 100) {
        NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
        NSError *error;

        NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

        if(!JSON || ![JSON count])
        {
            NSLog(@"%@", @"geen correcte json data van request gekregen");
        }
        else
        {
            data = JSON;
        }
    }
}

- (void) requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *) request
{
    NSError *error = [request error];
    NSLog(@"Error: %@",error.localizedDescription);
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [data count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [UITableViewCell alloc];
    }

    NSArray *namen = [data objectForKey:@"name"];
    cell.textLabel.text = [namen objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Thanks to some debugging i now know that the ASIHttpRequest works, but the NSdictionary that i create (and intent to use around the entire app) gives me the trouble. Can somebody set me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to be at:

```
NSArray *namen = [data objectForKey:@"name"];
```

So I think `data` type isn't correct (NSDictionary), is nil or it is filled with another type:

```
[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

Try seeing what arrives to you via JSON. For example:

```
NSError *jsonError = nil;
id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:&jsonError];

if ([jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    NSLog(@"its an array!");
    NSArray *jsonArray = (NSArray *)jsonObject;
    NSLog(@"jsonArray - %@",jsonArray);
    } else {
    NSLog(@"its probably a dictionary");
    NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = (NSDictionary *)jsonObject;
    NSLog(@"jsonDictionary - %@",jsonDictionary);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, should i have mentioned that i'm quite new to IOS developing. What do mean by making data and JSON type's ID?